# git/gitolite: big git repo with several mini projects

Tags: git, nas, gitolite

I'm pretty new to the whole version control thing, and even more so with git. I recently installed git on my computer(s) and set it up on a NAS server.

However, I have several client folders with several project folders per client folder.

Each one of these client folders is a giant repo, encompassing every project inside it.

What I'm wondering is, is there a way to break this apart?  So, for instance:

1. The NAS is my 'origin', and has gitolite installed
2. On computer1 I have every project folder in a client folder ever created (clean branch),
3. In computer2 I do *not* a new checkout of the client branch (because all the projects in that branch are all completed and I don't need a working copy of it), but I *do* have a brand new project folder for that client "newproject".

Is there a way to commit and push to the NAS repo from computer2?

Or perhaps is there a better way of organizing all this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better organization of Git repositories is to have one repo per client project (ie, many repo within your client folders: one .git within each client folder subdirectories which match a project root directory).

The idea of having one giant repo per client isn't necessary a good idea, especially:

- if that folder is composed of projects which can evolve independently one from another.
- if the sum total is huge in volume (which means any clone will be a big one)

If some of those projects are linked together, you still can view them as one (parent) repo, with the notion of **[submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html)**.